# Not getting desired return from method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In the #play_song method, I need to show the list of songs generated by the #list_songs method. There are many other classes in other files I have not included here, but all tests up until now are passing. The list_songs method is not returning the list how it is supposed to look: 1. Artist name - Song name - Genre, 2...

It is instead returning an array of objects. I don't get it because my tests are passing for #list_songs, which requires that the songs are outputed in the format I just described. So why is calling #list_songs within the play_song method returning an array of objects instead of displaying the list as 1. 2 3 ...?

```
class MusicLibraryController
  extend Concerns::Findable
  attr_accessor :path

  def initialize(path = './db/mp3s')
    music_importer = MusicImporter.new(path)
    music_importer.import
  end

  def call
    response = nil
    until response == "exit" do
      puts "Welcome to your music library!"
      puts "To list all of your songs, enter 'list songs'."
      puts "To list all of the artists in your library, enter 'list artists'."
      puts "To list all of the genres in your library, enter 'list genres'."
      puts "To list all of the songs by a particular artist, enter 'list artist'."
      puts "To list all of the songs of a particular genre, enter 'list genre'."
      puts "To play a song, enter 'play song'."
      puts "To quit, type 'exit'."
      puts "What would you like to do?"
      response = gets
    end
  end

  def list_songs
    #"1. Thundercat - For Love I Come - dance" order by song name
    ordered_songs = Song.all.uniq.sort_by {|song| song.name} #need to use "uniq" because there are duplicates of each song for some reason
    ordered_songs.each do |song|
      number = ordered_songs.index(song) + 1
      puts  "#{number}. #{song.artist.name} - #{song.name} - #{song.genre.name}"
    end
  end

  def list_artists
    ordered_artists = Artist.all.sort_by {|artist| artist.name}
    ordered_artists.each do |artist|
      number = ordered_artists.index(artist) + 1
      puts "#{number}. #{artist.name}"
    end
  end

  def list_genres
    ordered_genres = Genre.all.sort_by {|genre| genre.name}
    ordered_genres.each do |genre|
      number = ordered_genres.index(genre) + 1
      puts "#{number}. #{genre.name}"
    end
  end

  def list_songs_by_artist
    puts "Please enter the name of an artist:"
    artist_name = gets
    artist = Artist.all.select { |artist| artist.name == artist_name }.first #need to use .first b/c there are duplicates of each object and we want to select only one object
    if artist != nil
      ordered_songs = artist.songs.sort_by {|song| song.name}
      i = 1
      ordered_songs.each do |song|
        puts "#{i}. #{song.name} - #{song.genre.name}"
        i += 1
      end
    end
  end

  def list_songs_by_genre
    puts "Please enter the name of a genre:"
    genre_name = gets
    genre = Genre.all.select { |genre| genre.name == genre_name }.first
    if genre != nil
      ordered_songs = genre.songs.sort_by {|song| song.name}
      i = 1
      ordered_songs.each do |song|
        puts "#{i}. #{song.artist.name} - #{song.name}"
        i += 1
      end
    end
  end
  binding.pry


  def play_song
    list_songs
    puts "Which song number would you like to play?"
  end
end
```

Comment: list_songs isn't returning the textual list, it's outputting it

Comment: @JacobMattison `list_songs` is both outputting the list via `puts` in the `each` loop and returning an `Array<Song>` because the return value for `each` is the list itself.

Comment: Remember that in Ruby only `nil` and `false` are logically false, everything else is logically true, so it's rare you'll need to explicitly test against `nil`. It's only in occasions where you need to differentiate between potential `false` and `nil` that you'd do it.

Comment: engineersmnky -- that's my point. he's generating text but looking at the return value -- which is the array.